# Is there a way to swap the [Left Alt] key and [Tab] key on the keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, layout

Is there a way to swap the <kbd>Left Alt</kbd> key and <kbd>Tab</kbd> key on the keyboard?

Long story short I have a family member that lost their left-hand pinky and we want to remap the keys for them,

Their current keyboard layout is English (US),

Asus laptop
Running Ubuntu 20.04 focal
with the Cinnamon Desktop Environment 4.4.8

Answer (score 2):

You can edit xbd file:
(`/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/pc`).

In this case you will make these entries:

```
key <Alt> { [Tab] }
key <Tab> { [Alt] }
```

Clear xkb settings cache:
`rm -rf var/lib/xkb/*`

Reboot, and your keys will be mapped.

Also there is another way Xmodmap in latest ubuntu but changes are lost after reboot. For Xmodmap, please refer this [article](https://sites.ualberta.ca/dept/chemeng/AIX-43/share/man/info/C/a_doc_lib/cmds/aixcmds6/xmodmap.htm)

P.S. I haven't tested this in Ubuntu 20.04, however i have used this method in the past, so you can try this once.